# Failed to load Optix Kernel (kernel_optix.ptx)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, error

After changing GPU to a RTX 3090 and setting Blender 3.1.2 to render cycles using OptiX (also tried CUDA), my renders only make it to about 30 frames before the textures start to break in various ways like becoming black or purple. After 3 failed frames like this the render just quits and I can no longer render anything or even change to rendered viewport unless I restart the software.

If I quit the render before all 3 of the failed renders are done, and I try to change to rendered viewport, I get the error:
Failed to load OptiX kernel from '...Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\cycles\lib/kernel_optix.ptx'

It also happens if I change the viewport shading back and forth from the rendered mode around 30 times as well. I have tried installing the CUDA SDK, and reinstalled Nvidia drivers.

Edit:
Here's what happens to the render after ~30 rendered frames or going back and forth into the rendered viewport shading the same amount of times.
[image: Finished 30]
[image: Frame 31]
[image: Frame 32]
[image: Frame 33]

After the third failed frame it will always stop trying to render entirely, the only way I can see the error message is if I quit before the third failed frame is done and try to go into the rendered viewport, then this appears:
[image]

It can also be this:
[image]

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of your problems and maybe the text of the error message in the post? Any extra info you provide will make answering your question that much easier.

Comment: Your installation seems broken.  Those messages indicate that part of the Blender driver kernels that are kept in files is missing or can't be reached because of a permissions problem.  Use the file browser to cd to the cycles folder and see if libkernel_optix.ptx is there or not.  If not, uninstall and reinstall blender.